# What import is missing to make Spark's MLlib linear regression in Scala example work?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Using Spark v1.0-rc3 - When implementing MLlib's linear regression I get an error. So eventually I tried copy/pasting from [Spark's MLlib example code](http://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.1/mllib-guide.html#linear-regression-1) for linear regression in Scala and I still receive the error:

`scala> val parsedData = data.map { line =>
     val parts = line.split(',')
     LabeledPoint(parts(0).toDouble, parts(1).split(' ').map(x => x.toDouble).toArray)
     }
<console>:28: error: polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : [U >: Double]Array[U]
 required: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
         LabeledPoint(parts(0).toDouble, parts(1).split(' ').map(x => x.toDouble).toArray)`

The error states that `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector` is required, but importing it does not help. Even when trying multiple methods of casting to a Vector I get

`<console>:19: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Array[Double]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is due to changes to the later version. The code that once worked in v0.91 now requires tweaking for v1.0. You can find the [latest docs here](http://people.csail.mit.edu/matei/spark-unified-docs/mllib-classification-regression.html#linear-regression-least-squares-lasso-and-ridge-regression) The solution is to add Vectors not Vector despite what the error tells you. Try:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LinearRegressionWithSGD
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors

// Load and parse the data
val data = sc.textFile("mllib/data/ridge-data/lpsa.data")
val parsedData = data.map { line =>
  val parts = line.split(',')
  LabeledPoint(parts(0).toDouble, Vectors.dense(parts(1).split(' ').map(x => x.toDouble)))
  }
```